# MS sql. Not inserted value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, insert

In our company we using many DB servers in different cities. Sometimes data in one server should be synchronized with another. For example, in table "Monitor" values "status" and "date" may be updated very often. My problem is when theese values updated in server A, they also should be updated in server B:

- `Update Monitor set(date='2013-06-13')`
  and then
- 'Update Monitor set(status=4)'

  in server A udating of both values is sucsessfull, but in server B (usualy with highest loading) somtimes,  in approx. 0.03% cases updated only value `date` and `status` is stil old. Can anybody explain, is it possible in DB server with high loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to explain without looking at the boxes, logs and workload each is doing; there are a thousand things that would cause server "B" to miss data, including table and row locks, requests dropped by the network, unfinished transactions and the like. To find out exactly, you'd have to turn on the logging and compare the requests on "A" versus "B". The first thing I'd do, however, would be to look for errors in the SQL logs.

But in general keeping database synchronized across regions is do-able using existing technologies available in MS and Oracle. One scenario involves using a master, central db to receive all requests. It then distributes inserts, updates, delete and queries out to the regional DBs using SSIS or regular DB connectivity over a WAN.

Here's a high-level guide to the technology solution available in SQL Server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868047.aspx

You were probably looking for a simple answer, but I don't think there is one.